# image from database but input required still fires

Tags: php, html, image, jscript

How do i tell my INPUT FIELD that an image is present if i receive the data in the form of a variable from the database. 
As my Input has to be required..

I retrieve the image from the database as previously selected on the page before but the input does not know that a file is present as the file is a php variable..

The code below my help.

Thank you for any advice. Well appreciated.

```
<div class='imagecontainer'>    
    <div class='image1' id='image1'  title='Upload The 1st Image'  >

 <img id='img1' <?php if (!empty($i1url)) { echo " src='{$i1url}' "; } else { echo " src='' style='opacity:0;' "; } ?> onclick=' document.getElementById("sellimage1").click();'  class='imageclass'  ></img>

    <div class='cancel'  onClick='cancelimage(sellimage1 , img1, old1);' title='Delete This Image'> </div>  

    <input type='file' class='fileinput'  id='sellimage1' name='sellimage1' onchange='addimg(this , img1, image1);' value='' accept='image/*' required ></input>
    <input id='Chosen1' type='hidden' name='Chosenimg1' value='<?php echo $i1url; ?>' ></input> 

</div>
```

Comment: <?php if (!empty($i1url)) { echo " value='{$i1url}' "; } else { echo " value=' '  "; } ?>  Would this work --- NOPE!!!

Answer (score 0):

JS

input.required=false;
input.required=true;

Was my solution Along with PHP As follow on the INPUT Field

```
<div class='image1' id='image1'  title='Upload The 1st Image'  >

     <img id='img1' <?php if (!empty($i1url)) { echo " src='{$i1url}' "; } else { echo " src='' style='opacity:0;' "; } ?> onclick=' document.getElementById("sellimage1").click();'  class='imageclass'  ></img>

    <div class='cancel'  onClick='cancelimage(sellimage1 , img1, old1);' title='Delete This Image'> </div>  

    <div class='magnify' title='Magnify This Image' <?php echo " src='{$i1url}' "; ?> > </div>      

    <input type='file' class='fileinput'  id='sellimage1' name='sellimage1' onchange='addimg(this , img1, image1);' <?php if (!empty($i1url)) { echo " value='{$i1url}' "; } else { echo " value='' "; } ?> accept='image/*' <?php if (empty($i1url)) { echo " required "; } ?>   ></input>

    <input id='old1' type='hidden' name='oldimg1' value='<?php echo $i1url; ?>' ></input>   

</div>
```

JS

```
function cancelimage(a , b , c){


var image = b;

var value1 = a;

var value2 = c;

value1.value=null;
value2.value=null;

b.style.opacity='0';
b.style.transition='2s';

value1.required=true;


return

}





function addimg(input , image , main) {
 var lb=image;      
 var ab=main;       

 input.required=false;

 lb.src="../pageimages/loader.gif";
 lb.style.transition='.4s';
 lb.style.opacity='1';          


    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {


        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        sr=(e.target.result)
                    };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }

        setTimeout(function(){
        lb.src=""+sr;
        },2000);


}
```

Comment: But i see this as a very flimsy work around, i am sure there is a much better method that is more secure and preferred . Any further info would still be appreciated. Thank you.